# How to share data between cmdlets in a module?

Tags: powershell, module

I'm currently working on a module in PowerShell which uses a standard REST API in the background. For that, I wrote a `Connect-Server` cmdlet that retrieves an auth key for later calls.
My question is: Is there any best practice regarding sharing the data with other cmdlets? I know I could easily just return it from the `Connect` function and pass it to the following cmdlet, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Until now, I've been using global variables for that exchange of data. But as I've read in some best practice guidelines you should try not to pollute the global scope.
Other solutions I've seen use `Get` and `Set` cmdlets, but I don't think that's the best PowerShell way of doing it.

So are there any other ways of solving that?

Comment: So you want a cmdlet to create an object wich other cmdlets can use? I think the standard way would be to return the value so that you can store it in a variable or pipe it yourself...

Comment: `$Variable = Get-RestAPIResponse -Param1 Stuff -Param2 OtherStuff`
Use $Variable in another cmdlet. Ensure your `Get-RestAPIResponse` returns some JSON and just do a `| ConvertFrom-JSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the guys at [PoshCode](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/issues/139) stated, the best way to do such a thing is using a variable in script scope as this is available for all cmdlets in the module but not visible for users.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to return data from one cmdlet and store it either in a variable or forward it to the pipeline. Another way of sharing data might be serializing (`ConverTo-Json`, `ConvertTo-Csv`, ...) it to a file (located in e.g. `$env:TEMP`, or created via `New-Temporaryfile`), and deserializing it back again in another cmdlet (at cost of DISK I/O). Personally I'm always the result in a variable for lather usage and inject it in the next cmdlet (or use the pipeline).

Using global variables is not the best idea since you don't know on which parameters your cmdlet/function depends on.

Comment: So as mentioned in the question my goal was that I don't need to store it in a variable and pass it to other functions.
The reason for that is that in the mentioned example i would have to pass a session key to all cmdlets used and this leads to a bad user experience in my opinion.

The file option might definitely be an option for bigger objects.